# Check if an object has a property of a certain type

Tags: typescript, date, generics, type-safety

I'm trying to work out how to use generics to convert a date which is split into multiple parts into a Date object.

So far, I have this:

```js
export const convertDate = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => {
  const k = String(key)
  const [month, day, year] = [obj[`${k}-month`], obj[`${k}-day`], obj[`${k}-year`]]

  if (month && day && year) {
    obj[key] = new Date(year, month, day)
  }

  return obj
}
```

Which I'd like to use like so:

```
interface MyObjectWithADate {
  date?: Date
  ['date-year']: string
  ['date-month']: string
  ['date-day']: string
}
const obj: MyObjectWithADate = {
  'date-year': '2022',
  'date-month': '12',
  'date-day': '11',
}

convertDate(obj, 'date')
# obj.date = new Date(2022, 12, 11)
```

However, the compiler gives me the error `Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.`

How do I ensure my object can recieve a type of `Date`?

Playground link is below:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7ycgbsWARAQxmDgF44AeAFQBo4BpOUY5AE1TgGtgBPCAMzhUAfAAoIAIwBWALiF1uPOfQCUZYXADeAWABQcRCnRcycAMowoAS2QBzUYpV6DmYwG0AtihgALOqwIeOh5gAigAXVM3SSk3AAMAEk1OAF8AWi9kXzjwuhj4pNS0gJ4cvOkC5PSQsJzwvWc4K0FRTN84ADIOuBLO7pqoNR19Azh8xUjyZGAAdzhCYlEBuja-HsCnEZSGkahgGABXKGQx6T1t3R29G2IofgIEEgBZHgB5aWAEGAB1K18AQQWJGGBgCxAA-HIgY03AByMHANIDWHhOToax2GHwoiI1YotGWGy2LEI4qBfFwdFE856VzwGJyF7vKSfH5-HyAnGmEFwbHEJGhKCwuSwgBMAAZRaLYTRGnzcd4fMLeQBGaWykbysk8ZWwlUqmU0y66TA4fA48TSOjy2EqIA

Comment: The main issue is that an arbitrary generic type `T` is not known to have a `Date` property at key `K`, nor is it known to have strings at `\`${K}-year\``, etc.  You don't want `T` do be another generic type parameter; instead it should be a function of `K`.  Stuff unrelated to the main issue that also needs fixing: `String(key)` is going to be the same as `\`${key}\`` so you might as well skip it.  `new Date()` doesn't take three strings, it takes three numbers, so you should change it.  My suggested version of your code looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyeA2W).  Does that ...

Comment: ... meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's done the trick - thanks!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your version of `convertDate` is that it is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of `obj`, but `T` isn't known to have a `Date`-valued property at key `K` (we know `K extends keyof T`, so `T` has *some* property at `K`, but it could be of any type whatsoever). Furthermore, `T` isn't known to have keys at `` `${K}-year` ``, `` `${K}-month` ``, or `` `${K}-day` ``, so you can't safely index into `obj` with those keys.

If you know `K` is the type of the `key` parameter, then we can express the type of `obj` in terms of it without needing to have another generic type parameter.  It looks something like this:

```
type DateHavingObj<K extends string | number> =
  { [P in `${K}-${"year" | "month" | "day"}`]: string } &
  { [P in K]?: Date };
```

That's an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of two [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  First we have an object type whose keys are [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) you get when you concatenate `K` to `"-year"`, `"-month"`, or `"-day"`, and whose property values are `string`s.  And then we have an object type with an optional property whose key is `K` and whose value is `Date`.

Now the call signature is like

```
const convertDate = <K extends string | number>(
  obj: DateHavingObj<K>, key: K
) => { }
```

And we can see that it works when you call it on your `MyObjectWithADate`-typed `obj` if `key` is `"date"`:

```
convertDate(obj, "date"); // okay
```

but fails if you call it with some other `key`:

```
convertDate(obj, "fake"); // error!
// -------> ~~~ 
/* Type 'MyObjectWithADate' is missing properties 
   "fake-year", "fake-month", "fake-day" */
```

---

Anyway, we need to tweak the implementation of `convertDate()` a bit to make it compile with no errors:

```
const convertDate = <K extends string | number>(
  obj: DateHavingObj<K>, key: K
) => {
  const [month, day, year] = [
    Number(obj[`${key}-month`]),
    Number(obj[`${key}-day`]),
    Number(obj[`${key}-year`])
  ];
  const o: { [P in K]?: Date } = obj;
  if (month && day && year) {
    o[key] = new Date(year, month, day)
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The changes I made:

- We don't need to write `String(key)` if we're just going to use the result inside a [template literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  And the compiler doesn't understand that `String(key)` results in a value of type `` `${K}` ``, but it *does* understand that the `` `${key}` `` results in a value of that type.  So we might as well use `key` directly in the template  literal strings.
- The `Date` constructor takes year/month/day `number`s as input, not `string`s.  So we need to convert the values to `number` via `Number()` (or via unary `+`, or something).
- Since `DateHavingObject<K>` is an intersection of two generic types, and the compiler doesn't like assigning to the `K` property.  In order to prevent an error, we (mostly safely) upcast `obj` from `DateHavingObject<K>` to just the `{[P in K]?: Date}` part, and then do the assignment the `K` property of that.

And let's make sure it still works:

```
console.log(obj.date?.toUTCString()) //  "Wed, 11 Jan 2023 06:00:00 GMT"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAJOA3AlgOwOYHkBGAVgDwDSUEAHopgCYDOU9wATltlAD5SYCuAtvggsAfFAC8AWABQUKAG8oAbQAKULFAAGAEnmkAvgFpdAIhAQ4LE1ygn+Ae0zAAFte4nacECf2aAugBcTKzsUPpQAGQycoqq6phQpH4A-EHwiGEA3DIyAMaOzFD5mKjCwOnQ4lBkFNQQdIzMbDg2fILCIgAU0VD2RGkIyGjsBCSkIgA0UADWECBBpDIAlBJi8j3FhUoOTs5TniBT5pZ+Eso9cgByAkIsnX2ESjrysyBGOy7+SxMXUNftdweT10ryMBy+P1kcj+N2E9yIwJecyMxxYXx6fmyUM2wF6QViag0SVSsEGYTODyxcnQADMoJ0Ps5IhEoAdmVBUSt1lC5PYlK9TlVMBAAO6kxCdVFTRn7LxLHr6HosCDAXgsBKUmSK6QyLCIFg0uC5aAAWRAowguWAAHV0C4AIIVBQ9TyIEkVHpKADkroghlRXsCwWa2E9PsGhkZgaCTXYYd9hgO0eDcek2pxvX6UDNFqttodTqq3Lk4cQ-osLC9QS9ACYAAw1mteyElhNR6sARibLagpb9Sc7HebWpy0mKpRY5UG8MIUw8gxMS0yUAA9CvetMvHlHBOpxKHnPDbNF8u1xQWCx7CwAIQyM+GB+PwxiAB+b6gd4AVFAACrgaBejmRCWjadrOI6gxeuojD8Og9D0KEYCXpAk7oBAjAmEefqoiYh5wLMkaOC4uG2FhiZeNYn4rqOmz2AANhAAB0dH2NgM6Mb6ySMcA9gAKo-gAwgAyiEOCdEsKxnrY1oQLQUwdh2UAAFJwAk9Y1gAzFAdYAGwBHWdb6XWUAAOImj+1gyEAA)